# find peaks and envelope question in python

Tags: python

I want find to upper, lower peaks and interpolate them. (envelope)
In MATLAB, there is envelope function, but python doesn't have that.
How can I draw the envelope curve?

File format is .csv
data format is:

```
150*2 array
1    14.7
2    14.58
3    14.82
4    14.59
5    14.67
...  ...
150  13.76
```

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from pandas import read_csv
df=pd.read_csv('Test.csv')
x=df.time[0:]
y=df.data[0:]
import scipy.signal
indexes = scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt(y, np.arange(1, 4), max_distances=np.arange(1, 4))
indexes = np.array(indexes) - 1
for n in range(len(indexes)):
    print(y[indexes[n]])
print(indexes)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(indexes, y[indexes])
indexes_l = scipy.signal.find_peaks_cwt(-y, np.arange(1, 4), max_distances=np.arange(1, 4)*0.5)
indexes_l = np.array(indexes_l) - 1
for n in range(len(indexes_l)):
    print(y[indexes_l[n]])
print(indexes_l)
plt.plot(indexes_l, y[indexes_l])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement [scipy.signal.hilbert](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.hilbert.html).

To get you started:

```
upper_envelope = np.abs(scipy.signal.hilbert(y))
```

would give you an envelope on the upper side, then you're left with plotting it however you like.

Comment: can you recommend for example?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [findpeaks library](https://erdogant.github.io/findpeaks). Multiple methods are available such as [topology](https://erdogant.github.io/findpeaks/pages/html/Topology.html) method and [peakdetect](https://erdogant.github.io/findpeaks/pages/html/Peakdetect.html).

```
pip install findpeaks
```

Example:

```
# Import library
from findpeaks import findpeaks

X = [9,60,377,985,1153,672,501,1068,1110,574,135,23,3,47,252,812,1182,741,263,33]
fp = findpeaks(lookahead=1, interpolate=10)
results = fp.fit(X)
fp.plot()
```

[image: findpeaks on raw data]
[image: Find peaks with smoothing]

The output contains the low/high peaks, and also the smoothed line.

```
# Results
results['df']
results['df_interp']
```